# Correct Placeholder Code Fit Width Area and Adjust Height and Placeholder Icon in the. middle

Tags: swift, swiftui, kingfisher

I am not sure what is lacking with regards to adding a placeholder using king fisher. This is the code

```
NavigationLink {
                    CustomView()
                }
                label: {
                    KFImage.url(URL(string: imageUrl)!)
                        .placeholder {
                            Image(systemName: "photo")
                        }
                        .fade(duration: 0.25)
                        .onFailure { error in print("Load image error : \(error) = \(earthquakeDetail.imgUrl)")
                        }
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                }
```

So when the image is successfully downlaoded, it fills the whole width and height is adjusted porportional to the width.

For the placeholder, what happens is that the icon is so small and the width and height area is bigger thant he area occupied when the image is successfully downloaded and displayed.

Please see images highlighted in yellow and green square. I tried adding an HStack wrapping the Image while setting the frame(width: .infinity) but didnt work out the way I wanted to.

What could I be missing here? I also need the image placeholder width with value 80 (using .frame(width: 80) but it also did not work out.

[image]
[image]

Comment: you can set the `.font` on the image e.g. `.font(.largeTitle)` to change the size of an icon

Comment: hi @Carsten thank you for the suggestion. it did become a bit bigger than the original but not the size that i was expecting. Chris suggestion works for my use case.

Comment: did you try using a custom system font with a bigger fontsize as mentioned by Chris?

Comment: Yes. the custom system font size worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, you would like the icon to be bigger than the default size, if that's the case, you will need to either change the size of the image using the font style `.font(.system(size: CGFloat(fontSize)))` or using the code below:

```
NavigationLink {
    CustomView()
} label: {
    KFImage.url(URL(string: imageUrl)!)
    .placeholder {
        Image(systemName: "photo")
        .resizable()
        .frame(width: 80)
    }
    .fade(duration: 0.25)
    .onFailure { error in print("Load image error : \(error) = \(earthquakeDetail.imgUrl)")
    }
    .resizable()
    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
}
```

A resizeable needs to be added to the placeholder because the second resizable will only work on the image once it has loaded. Hope this helps!

Comment: 2 things actually. 1 is make the icon size bigger. which, yours does work. The other is that it should be placed in the middle of an area where the same width and height will be occupied once the image loads. I am not sure what the right way to do this is. Placing it inside an HStack and setting frame(width: .infinity) didnt work.

Comment: ill go ahead and mark your answer as correct since the title itself somewhat describes the issue as only the size of the icon.